# Error when Loading a .pb Tensorflow Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I created a tensorflow model on a Windows 10 machine and saved it using:

```
model.save('myfolder')
```

Inside the folder `myfolder` I get:

```
- saved_model.pb
- Variables folder
- Assets folder
```

Now I'm trying to load the model in a Linux machine, so I'm passing the folder path as the model path to load it:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('myfolder')
```

It actually detects the model but throw this huge error:

```
2020-09-27 18:43:57.980054: W tensorflow/core/graph/graph_constructor.cc:772] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 44 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2020-09-27 18:44:02.211495: W tensorflow/core/graph/graph_constructor.cc:772] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 44 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2020-09-27 18:44:02.376792: W tensorflow/core/graph/graph_constructor.cc:772] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 45 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2020-09-27 18:44:16.361762: W tensorflow/core/graph/graph_constructor.cc:772] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 45 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2020-09-27 18:44:18.184022: W tensorflow/core/graph/graph_constructor.cc:772] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 44 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2020-09-27 18:44:18.331177: W tensorflow/core/graph/graph_constructor.cc:772] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 45 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2020-09-27 18:44:19.087747: W tensorflow/core/graph/graph_constructor.cc:772] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 44 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2020-09-27 18:44:22.933245: W tensorflow/core/graph/graph_constructor.cc:772] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 44 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2020-09-27 18:44:23.074951: W tensorflow/core/graph/graph_constructor.cc:772] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 45 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2020-09-27 18:44:28.451176: W tensorflow/core/graph/graph_constructor.cc:772] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 44 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2020-09-27 18:44:28.597107: W tensorflow/core/graph/graph_constructor.cc:772] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 45 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2020-09-27 18:44:33.579605: W tensorflow/core/graph/graph_constructor.cc:772] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 44 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2020-09-27 18:44:33.742273: W tensorflow/core/graph/graph_constructor.cc:772] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 45 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2020-09-27 18:44:51.043732: W tensorflow/core/graph/graph_constructor.cc:772] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 44 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2020-09-27 18:44:57.151346: W tensorflow/core/graph/graph_constructor.cc:772] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 45 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2020-09-27 18:45:00.168905: W tensorflow/core/graph/graph_constructor.cc:772] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 44 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2020-09-27 18:45:00.312153: W tensorflow/core/graph/graph_constructor.cc:772] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 45 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2020-09-27 18:45:01.051383: W tensorflow/core/graph/graph_constructor.cc:772] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 44 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2020-09-27 18:45:01.190471: W tensorflow/core/graph/graph_constructor.cc:772] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 45 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2020-09-27 18:45:01.395016: W tensorflow/core/graph/graph_constructor.cc:772] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 44 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2020-09-27 18:45:01.542457: W tensorflow/core/graph/graph_constructor.cc:772] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 45 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2020-09-27 18:45:05.023475: W tensorflow/core/graph/graph_constructor.cc:772] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 44 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2020-09-27 18:45:05.235829: W tensorflow/core/graph/graph_constructor.cc:772] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 45 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2020-09-27 18:45:05.568045: W tensorflow/core/graph/graph_constructor.cc:772] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 45 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2020-09-27 18:45:06.300144: W tensorflow/core/graph/graph_constructor.cc:772] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 44 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2020-09-27 18:45:06.439828: W tensorflow/core/graph/graph_constructor.cc:772] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 45 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2020-09-27 18:45:11.585829: W tensorflow/core/graph/graph_constructor.cc:772] Node 'cond/while' has 13 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 44 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
2020-09-27 18:45:11.729289: W tensorflow/core/graph/graph_constructor.cc:772] Node 'cond' has 5 outputs but the _output_shapes attribute specifies shapes for 45 outputs. Output shapes may be inaccurate.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 95, in <module>
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model')
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/save.py", line 150, in load_model
    return saved_model_load.load(filepath, compile)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 89, in load
    model = tf_load.load_internal(path, loader_cls=KerasObjectLoader)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/load.py", line 541, in load_internal
    export_dir)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 118, in __init__
    super(KerasObjectLoader, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/load.py", line 121, in __init__
    self._load_all()
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/load.py", line 239, in _load_all
    node, setter = self._recreate(proto)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/load.py", line 322, in _recreate
    return factory[kind]()
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/load.py", line 309, in <lambda>
    "user_object": lambda: self._recreate_user_object(proto.user_object),
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/load.py", line 328, in _recreate_user_object
    return self._recreate_base_user_object(proto)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 216, in _recreate_base_user_object
    return revived_cls._init_from_metadata(metadata)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 297, in _init_from_metadata
    revived_obj = cls(**init_args)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/input_layer.py", line 86, in __init__
    batch_size = batch_input_shape[0]
KeyError: 0
```

I have already searched in Tensorflow issues from GitHub but I haven't found anythin interesting yet. I saw a [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63321129/13071340) recommending create a new model with the weights of the loaded one but I can't even do it because I get the error while the loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved the same problem.

Check the version of Tensorflow that you are using to train and save your model and the version that you are using to load it. They must be the same or, at least, [compatible versions](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/versions).

Comment: I added 'compile=False' as parameter to ''tf.keras.models.load_model()'' and seems to be working, I'm still trying to understand why this happens (I was using the same version of TF fot training and predicting)

Comment: @DRRorresRuiz I have same problem.... Also I checked tensorflow version in save and load environment. They were same version.